# Left join three tables with where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

can anyone tell me whats the error with this query Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN where YEAR at line 1

```
SELECT uw.user_id, cd.LEW, cd.event_date,dd.hwRate,d3.Wdata
FROM user_worker AS uw
LEFT JOIN _device1 AS cd ON uw.user_id = cd.uuid     
WHERE YEAR(cd.event_date)=2018 
LEFT JOIN _device2 AS dd ON uw.user_id = dd.uuid 
WHERE YEAR(dd.event_date)=2018 
LEFT JOIN _device3 AS d3 ON uw.user_id = d3.uuid 
WHERE YEAR(d3.event_date)=2018
```

Comment: Only 1 where clause is allowed after  from and all the joins - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: Replace every `WHERE` with `AND`.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, you can't have multi where for each join, but if you replace all the where by a "AND", it will work :

```
SELECT uw.user_id, cd.LEW, cd.event_date,dd.hwRate,d3.Wdata
FROM user_worker AS uw
LEFT JOIN _device1 AS cd ON uw.user_id = cd.uuid     
 AND YEAR(cd.event_date)=2018 
LEFT JOIN _device2 AS dd ON uw.user_id = dd.uuid 
 AND YEAR(dd.event_date)=2018 
LEFT JOIN _device3 AS d3 ON uw.user_id = d3.uuid 
 AND  YEAR(d3.event_date)=2018
```